# Visual Stadio 2022「ASP.NET Core WEB アプリ(MVC)」の初期設定について

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Visual Stadio 2022「ASP.NET Core WEB アプリ(MVC)」

上記を利用して、プログラミングを開始したいと考えています。
Visual Studio Community 2022をダウンロードし、ワークロード「ASP.NETとWEB開発、Azureの開発、.NETデスクトップ開発、データの保存と処理」にチェックをつけて、インストールを行いました。

その後、新しいプロジェクトから「ASP.NET Core Web アプリ (Model-View-Controller)」を選択し、ソリューションファイルを作成するのですが、何度行ってもデバッグボタンが表示されません。

ほかの方と状況比較を行うと、ソリューションエクスプローラ内に作成される、各種コードが見えない状態となっているようです。

本件、解決策をご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【2023/04/28情報追記】

・自身の2台目のPCと本事象が生じてしまうPCで
　 ASP.NET Core MVC の概要　
　 (https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)
手順に沿って、全く同じ操作を実施したところ、2台目のPCでは、正常にデバッグ
　が実施できることを確認いたしました。(インストーラのダウンロード手順から実施)

問題のPC：windows11
　2台目のPC(動作成功したPC)：windows10

上記より、自身の操作方法ではなく環境差分(インストール完了後の初期設定の違い？)により本事象が生じてしまっている可能性が高いと考えています。
　設定の差分をチェックするうえで確認をすべきステータス等があればご教示いただけると幸いです

【2023/04/30 追記】
　事象回復いたしました。
　原因は、自身のPCにおける環境変数の優先順位に問題があったようです。

原因追求と問題解消までのプロセスを参考までに共有します。

①MS 開発者コミュニティにて同事象のコメントを検索 [URL](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-ASPNET-Core-Web-Application-C/804020?q=asp.net%20core%20mvc)
　 2019年の記事にて類似事象を確認
　 明確な原因等の言及はなかったが"SDK"絡みの問題であると予測
　
　②自身のPCにおけるglobal.jsonで指定されているSDKを調査　[URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows#check-sdk-versions)
ターミナルより返答がなく、おかしいと感じる

③PCにより指定しているSDKの応答がない事象に対する解決策を検索していると
　 類似事象の記事を発見　[URL](https://zenn.dev/yodoyodo/articles/f87141c478db5f)
システム環境変数の設定に不具合が生じており、記事の通り変更することで事象回復

Comment: この辺のチュートリアルとかの手順や確認は済んでいるのでしょうか？ [ASP.NET Core MVC の概要](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio), [ASP.NET Core MVCのチュートリアルを丁寧にやってみた①（プロジェクトの作成からビューの追加まで）](https://hirahira.blog/asp-net-core5-mvc-tutorial-01/)から始まる一連の記事, [ASP.NET Core MVC 公式チュートリアルから実開発への橋渡し](https://qiita.com/pepepe_90/items/795dadb8757ec0c5f948) それらとの違いは何かを意識されていますか？ そういう情報があれば追加してみてください。

Comment: あなたの言う「デバッグボタン」って何ですか？　ツールバーには［デバッグ(D)］ボタンは表示されてますが？

Comment: また「ASP.NET Core WEB アプリ(MVC)」というテンプレートは自分の環境の Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64 ビット) Version 17.5.4 には存在しません。ASP.NET Core MVC アプリを作りたいなら、「ASP.NET Core Web アプリ (Model-View-Controller)」になりますが、それはメニューに存在しますか？

Comment: >kunif様
掲載いただいた記事は確認しており、アプリの実行というセクションで、
動作が効かず、以降のフェーズに進めない状態となっております。

Comment: >Websurfer様
曖昧な表現で申し訳ありません。
「デバッグボタン」と表現したのは、画面上部の緑▲　再生ボタン部分になります。
チュートリアルでは、作成したプロジェクト名(今回でいうとWebApplication8)という表記となり、デバックの実行が可能となりWEBブラウザが立ち上がるようなのですが、自身の環境では、「アタッチ」という操作しかできないようになっており、フレームワークの中に存在するであろう初期のプログラムが動作していないように見えています。

Comment: また、ご指摘いただいた、当方の「ASP.NET Core WEB アプリ(MVC)」
という表現は「ASP.NET Core Web アプリ (Model-View-Controller)」のことでございます。

Comment: @オリナス さん、その辺の情報はコメントで応答するのではなく、質問記事を編集して追記や相応しい内容への詳細化を行ってください。あと最初のチュートリアルの途中でつまづいているのか、それともチュートリアル自身は正常に終了していて、別途新規に新しいソリューション/プロジェクトを始めた時に問題が発生しているのかが曖昧です。もしチュートリアルが正常に済んでいるなら、それとの違いを調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 質問に貼られた画像のソリューションエクスプローラーで「0 個のプロジェクト」となってます。チュートリアル通りにやってそういうことにはならないはずで、何か違うことをやっているか、質問者さん固有の環境の問題があって Visual Studio が期待どおり動いてないのではということぐらいしか自分には思い当たることが無いです。「ほかの方と状況比較」ができるそうなので、その人に見てもらって同じようにやってみることはできますか。

Comment: > WebSurfer様
質問に状況を更新させていただきました。
自身保有の2台目のPCにおいては、OSの違いはあれど、チュートリアル通りに操作をすることで、「0個のプロジェクト」とはならず、デバッグボタンが起動し、WEBブラウザページを呼び起こすことができました。固有の環境に問題があるようですが、どの項目を確認するべきなのか見当がつかず、ご知見あればご教示いただけると幸いです

Comment: 例えばVisualStudioのインストールで、対象「ワークロード」か「個別のコンポーネント」の選択に違いがあるか、PCの「コントロールパネル」・「プログラム」・「プログラムのアンインストール」・「Windowsの機能の有効化または無効化」で有効化された機能に違いが有るのかもしれません。あるいはログインしているユーザーのグループ分けや権限とか、PC毎の何かの細かいグループポリシーの違いという可能性かもしれません。いずれにしても対象PCにアクセスしてその違いや状況を調べられるのは @オリナス さんだけですし明確な原因や問題が判っているわけでは無いので漠然としたことしか言えないでしょう。

Comment: > 皆様
本件、事象の回復ができました。
問題解決までのプロセスと原因については、記事編集にて追記させていただいております。
自身で設定変更を行った領域ではないので、なぜこのような環境変更が起こっていしまっていたのかまでを特定することはできませんでしたが、
指定されたSDKを参照できていないことが問題の原因でした
はじめて、こちらで質問させていただきましたが、あたたかくアドバイスしてくださった皆様、本当にありがとうございました。
ようやくASP.NET Coreを利用した開発人生をスタートできそうです。

Comment: 解決した旨は質問にではなく、回答を自分で書いてください。

Answer (score 1):

事象回復いたしました。
　原因は、自身のPCにおける環境変数の優先順位に問題があったようです。

原因追求と問題解消までのプロセスを参考までに共有します。

①MS 開発者コミュニティにて同事象のコメントを検索 [URL](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Missing-ASPNET-Core-Web-Application-C/804020?q=asp.net%20core%20mvc)
　 2019年の記事にて類似事象を確認
　 明確な原因等の言及はなかったが"SDK"絡みの問題であると予測
　
　②自身のPCにおけるglobal.jsonで指定されているSDKを調査　[URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows#check-sdk-versions)
ターミナルより返答がなく、おかしいと感じる

③PCにより指定しているSDKの応答がない事象に対する解決策を検索していると
　 類似事象の記事を発見　[URL](https://zenn.dev/yodoyodo/articles/f87141c478db5f)
システム環境変数の設定に不具合が生じており、記事の通り変更することで事象回復

Comment: 出来れば情報共有や事例の記録のために、問題が発生していた時と解決した後の、それぞれの環境変数の具体的な並び方を書いておいてください。ユーザー名等の情報は適当に何かに置き換えて。問題時の情報が残っていないなら解決後の情報と何が原因だったらしいか程度のコメントでも良いでしょう。